# How to make grafana on nixos available in local network

Tags: nginx, networking, port, grafana, nixos

My laptop and my nixos-server (hostname=nixos) are both conected to my router (fritz.box). I can access the rooter via ping (ping nixos.fritz.box) and ssh (ssh username@nixos.fritz.box).

[image: network diagram]

What I want is to follow the first part of [this guide](https://christine.website/blog/prometheus-grafana-loki-nixos-2020-11-20) to set up grafana on nixos. I then want to be able to access grafana from my laptop.

On the server I have configured nixos to run both grafana and a reverse proxy (nginx):

```
  services.grafana = {
    enable = true;
    domain = "grafana.nixos.fritz.box";
    port = 2342;
    addr = "127.0.0.1";
  };

  # nginx reverse proxy for grafana
  services.nginx.virtualHosts.${config.services.grafana.domain} = {
    locations."/" = {
      proxyPass = "http://127.0.0.1:${toString config.services.grafana.port}";
      proxyWebsockets = true;
    };
  };

  # Open ports for http and https
  networking.firewall.allowedTCPPorts = [ 80 443 ];

  system.stateVersion = "21.03";
```

Unfortunatelly I can't access the grafana webinterface from my laptop.

I tried changing around the value of `services.grafana.domain` and what I type into my browser (firefox/curl), here is what I got:

| services.grafana.domain | argument of curl | output of curl |
| --- | --- | --- |
| grafana.nixos.fritz.box | http://grafana.nixos.fritz.box/ | curl: (6) Could not resolve host: grafana.nixos.fritz.box |
| grafana.nixos.fritz.box | https://grafana.nixos.fritz.box/ | curl: (6) Could not resolve host: grafana.nixos.fritz.box |
| grafana.nixos.fritz.box | http://nixos.fritz.box/ | curl: (52) Empty reply from server |
| grafana.nixos.fritz.box | https://nixos.fritz.box/ | curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to nixos.fritz.box:443 |
| nixos.fritz.box | http://nixos.fritz.box/ | curl: (52) Empty reply from server |
| nixos.fritz.box | https://nixos.fritz.box/ | curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to nixos.fritz.box:443 |
| grafana.localhost | (on the server) http://grafana.localhost | curl: (7) Failed to connect to grafana.localhost port 80: Connection refused |
| grafana.localhost | (on the server) https://grafana.localhost | curl: (7) Failed to connect to grafana.localhost port 443: Connection refused |

Especially the last 2 lines leave me perplexed.

`netstat -an | grep LISTEN` on the server gives me this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2342          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1837     /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1841     /run/systemd/userdb/io.systemd.DynamicUser
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     1853     /run/systemd/coredump
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1862     /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     1868     /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     26958    /var/run/nscd/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1905     /run/systemd/journal/io.systemd.journal
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12193659 /run/user/1001/bus
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12205464 /run/user/1001/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13312    /nix/var/nix/daemon-socket/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18416    /var/run/dhcpcd.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18418    /var/run/dhcpcd.unpriv.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13308    /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
```

I don't know how to make grafana available in the local network. Can someone help me with that, please?

(I know this question is somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64738440/how-to-make-zabbix-on-nixos-available-in-local-network/64792559#64792559), but the solution there doesn't help me)

Comment: first of all make sure your `nginx.service` is running and listening on port 80 which doesn't look like it from `netstat` you run.
then your server firewall is not blocking access to port 80 which seems so by the error message you get.

Comment: @Tch Good point. I found that `nginx.service.enable` was not set (and defaults to `false`). I wrote the author of the blogpost so she can add that. Do you want to write an answer so I can accept it? Btw, I can now access grafana over `nixos.fritz.box`, but would expect it to be  found under `grafana.nixos.fritz.box`. Do you happen to know why that it (or how I can change it)?

Comment: if that solved your issue, then you can write your own answer and accept it for others to see, and you can just up-vote my comments.

Comment: you have to find out who is responsible for the A record of this subdomain. if there is no active dns that provides you with that info then you have to set `ipofserver grafana.nixos.fritz.box` in your laptop's and server's /etc/hosts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following line solved my problem (thanks to @Tch):

```
services.nginx.enable = true;
```

Comment: Don't you mean `services.nginx.enable = true;`?

Comment: @l0b0 you are right, I edited my answer