# Have a webservice on a nixos server available under a subdomain

Tags: nginx, networking, server, webserver, nixos

#### What I have

Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64738440/how-to-make-zabbix-on-nixos-available-in-local-network) and it's answer I have a nixos server (hostname `nixos`, a raspberry pi) with zabbix installed on it. Zabbix can be accessed from the local network on `regulus.fritz.box`.

[image: Network: my computer is connected to a fritzbox router, which is also connected to the server]

My config:

```hs
  services.zabbixServer.enable = true;
  services.zabbixWeb = {
    enable = true;
    virtualHost = {
      adminAddr = "webmaster@localhost";
    };
  };
  networking.firewall.allowedTCPPorts = [ 80 443 ];
```

This works fine as it is.

But now I want to have more services running on the same server (grafana, a nextcloud, a webplayer for music ...) - and they can't all be available as `nixos.fritz.box`.

#### what I want

So now I want the service to live at one of the following:

1. `zabbix.nixos.fritz.box` or
2. `nixos.fritz.box/zabbix`.

I think I prefere the first one, but I don't care very much and will prefer simple and beautiful solutions over what seems to me like a nicer url.

Other services will then be available at similar domains, like `nextcloud.nixos.fritz.box`.

#### what I tried

As the whole setup is in a local network without a real domain I can't really change any DNS records (changing `/etc/hosts/` doesn't count as this is not possible for all devices in my network)

I suspect that the desired result can be achieved by using nginx and it's virtualhosts settings somehow, but I can't get it to work.

My best try so far is this:

```
  services.nginx = {
    enable = true;
    virtualHosts."someStringIDoNotKnow" = {
      locations."someOtherStringIDoNotKnow" = {
        proxyPass = "http://127.0.0.1:12345;
        proxyWebsockets = true;
      };
    };
  };
```

There is also a setting called `services.zabbixWeb.virtualHost`, for which I also don't know how it is supposed to be used.

Obviously I don't know what I am doing here. I especially don't understand what a virtual host is and if it can help me (and why both zabbixWeb and nginx have them).

So can someone please tell me (or link to sources explaining) how I can have a web service available under a subdomain/directory on a nixos server?